# How can we log Changes to User Permissions?

Tags: user-management

We have a requirement to log changes made to User Permissions. We have looked in the CM and did not find any history details for User Permissions changes.

Is it possible to get this information from the CM database? (We did not find any tables with history information when we looked) or can we use the Event System to log these changes?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Content Manager does not track those kinds of changes. You will need to create some kind of extension to do this yourself. I'd suggest using an [Event Handler](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-AB4FBF5F-7C3B-4804-9E7F-FBBF5514A596).

Be aware that tracking changes to just users would not necessarily be enough to achieve your requirement. Users are typically added as members of Groups and those Groups are then given certain rights within Publications, permissions on Folders, ability to use Target Types etc. To fully audit security you'd need to log all of those changes (and probably more).

Comment: Thanks David. That is what we thought. We will track and log the changes done in all user management items.